# Counting Pattern Occurrences in a Large Data frame without Iterating Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Jack   Joe   Mary
1    I      O     O
2    I      O     I
3    I      I     I
4    O      I     I
5    O      I     O
6    I      O     O
7    I      O     I
8    I      O     I
9    O      I     I
10   O      I     O
      ....
```

My columns have patterns of 'I I I' and 'O O O'  dispersed throughout.

I want to count the number of occurrences of 'I I I' and 'O O O' in each column.

I know I can iterate through each row of each column but this is a very large dataframe.

Does anyone have 1) a more efficient way to do this and 2) a more pythonic way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the "Jack" column and "I I I" pattern, for example.

Using shifting, we get

```
>>> (df.Jack == df.Jack.shift(1)) & (df.Jack == df.Jack.shift(2)) & (df.Jack == 'I')
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
Name: Jack, dtype: bool
```

so

```
((df.Jack == df.Jack.shift(1)) & (df.Jack == df.Jack.shift(2)) & (df.Jack == 'I')).sum()
```

gives the number of occurrences of the pattern in the column.

You can easily modify this to the other patterns and columns.

Note that "I I I I" would count as the pattern occurring twice (interlapped).

Comment: Thanks.  To your point about 'I I I I' counting twice - how can I eliminate?  Im looking for precise patterns of exactly (and only) 3 consecutive I's or O's

Answer (score 2):

What I will do

```
s=(df.shift()==df).ne(True).cumsum()# create the group key, class all continue value to one group
for x in s.columns:
    print(x,df[x].groupby(s[x]).apply(''.join).isin(['III','OOO']).sum())
Jack 2
Joe 2
Mary 2
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

You are counting the number of times `III` or `OOO` occurs.  I'd concat the strings and count

```
s = df.sum()
pd.concat({k: s.str.count(k) for k in ['III', 'OOO']}).unstack()

     Jack  Joe  Mary
III     2    1     2
OOO     0    1     0
```

You'll notice that this counts `'IIII'` as one instance of `'III'`.

Comment: `'IIIIII'.count('III')` counts `2`.  If I understood correctly, that solves the problem.  Its possible that I misunderstood though.

Comment: No, IMHO you understood it right. This is a really great way to solve it, and personally I was unaware of how `count` behaves. I think this should be the accepted answer, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply [`pd.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to each column of your dataframe, that way if you have more than just I and O you can easily count those values as well

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts)

   Jack  Joe  Mary
I     6    5     6
O     4    5     4
```